# Shutting down MySQL 4 correctly in Docker Container

Tags: mysql, docker

For some (very) legacy application, I need a MySQL 4 installation. Based on

- https://github.com/Tommi2Day/mysql4
- https://github.com/stevemayne/mysql4docker

I have created a docker container, which generally works fine. Roughly, they do the following things

- compile MySQL 4.1.25 from source
- add an entrypoint that does roughly the following thing

  ```
  if [ "$1" = 'mysqld_safe' ]; then
     # do some things to initialize database if required
  fi

  exec "$@"
  ```
- which is called using

  ```
  ENTRYPOINT ["/path/to/entrypoint.sh"]
  CMD ["mysqld_safe"]
  ```

However, I have the following problem: When stopping the docker container, it seems that `mysqld_safe` is not properly shutdown. When I'm restarting the container, I get the following error logs

```
170419 11:23:44  mysqld started
170419 11:23:44  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
170419 11:23:44  InnoDB: Starting log scan based on checkpoint at
InnoDB: log sequence number 0 43684.
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 0 43684
InnoDB: Last MySQL binlog file position 0 79, file name ./09601db873a9-bin.000003
170419 11:23:44  InnoDB: Flushing modified pages from the buffer pool...
170419 11:23:44  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 43684
/usr/local/mysql/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Verion: '4.1.25-log'  ssocket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
```

This seems to happen, because `mysqld_safe` basically ignores any signals (line 16 of `/usr/local/myslq/bin/mysqld_safe`):

```
trap '' 1 2 3 15            # we shouldn't let anyone kill us
```

This makes me think that maybe `mysqld_safe` is not the right way to start MySQL in the container? What is the recommended way to start and stop MySQL 4 in a docker container? (Unfortunately, the container will have to be stopped occassionally.)